# Intellij Idea компилирует за 6 секунд

Tags: intellij-idea, компиляция

Что делать, использую *Intellij Idea* компилирует *java* за 6 секунд, почему так долго? что делать? в том же нетбинсе все компилится за полсекунды.

Comment: `не так уж и долго` Ты издеваешься?

Comment: Chromium это крупная программа, а Hello world - нет

Comment: в том же нетбинсе все компилится за полсекунды

Comment: Таки 6 секунд - это не долго. Вот если бы компилировало Hello World дольше минуты - тогда стоило бы беспокоиться.

Comment: надо смотреть что у тебя стоит, какие настройки, какой проект, какие зависимости и пр. может у тебя там всякие мейвены и спринги стоят и ты там пытаешься хэлловордить

Comment: Это ещё повезло что компилируется. За что вообще требуют деньги jetbrains?

Comment: Ну есть и годные программы от JB, сейчас для джавы использую еклипс, скорость компиляции - 0.1 сек

Comment: хорошо что не покупал Ultimate